# guard/listen gem to work on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, guard, listen

The guard/listen gem works perfect when I run rails server -
it listens to changes in files and runs all kinds of scripts once there's a change.
but - it won't work when I run rails console.

here's the code that is in config/initializers/listen.rb:

```
Thread.new do
    puts "listening to changes in db/data directory"
    File.open("db/data/test.txt", 'a+'){ |f| f.puts "hello"} 
    Listen.to("db/data", :filter => /\.yml$/, :ignore => %r{ignored/path/}) do |modified, added, removed|
        File.open("db/data/test.txt", 'a+'){ |f| f.puts "file changed"} 
        puts "file changed"
    end
end
```

when i run rails console it prints the "listening to changes in db/data directory" line and stalls.

I think it has something to do with multithreading and blocking.

Is there a way to run listen with console?

thanks,
Michal Yashpe

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I will give my answer for anyone looking for this.
Does it stall or exit? Anyways it is suppose to exit...

When you start your rails app it doesn't exit and this is why it works, the listen gem, as Matt said, calls the block after Listen.to is called. When you start the script from a rails console, it will simply execute everything then exit. 
You need to add a `sleep` or a `gets` at the end to make sure your script never exits.

Answer (score 0):

List.to block does not get called until a change is made *after* Listen.to is called. You are attempting to change files before, and after, Listen fires a change event.

Move the "file changed" puts out side of the Thread.new

```
 Thread.new do
      puts "listening to changes in db/data directory"

      Listen.to("db/data", :filter => /\.yml$/) do |modified, added, removed|
        File.open("db/data/test.txt", 'a+'){ |f| f.puts "file changed"} 
        puts "file changed"
      end
  end
File.open("db/data/test.txt", 'w+'){ |f| f.puts "changed now"}
```

Try the callback method too and elim the thread: https://github.com/guard/listen#changes-callback